# How to generate 0x00000000FFFFFFFF long mask in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

The above doesn't work and returns -1 due to sign extension. So I'm wondering if there is a way to get the lower 32 bit only even if the long number is negative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `L` suffix to specify a `long` literal: `0x00000000ffffffffL`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps `0x00000000FFFFFFFFL` (note the `L` at the end, which is the [integer type suffix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) for `long`).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work just fine:

```
final long mask = 0x00000000FFFFFFFFL;
final long val = Long.MAX_VALUE;
final long masked = val & mask;
System.out.println(masked);
```

Output: 4294967295